# Bootstrap dropdown disappears after clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="serviceHistoryController">
    <!-- Search box Start -->
    <div class="dropdown col-xs-8">
          <button class="btn btn-default col-xs-4" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="true">
            Select SUT
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu col-xs-8" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li ng-repeat="sutname in sutlist">
                  <a href="#" ng-click="sutselected(sutname)">
                      {{sutname.name}}
                  </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above is the bootstrap + angular drop down code i am using. But once i clicked on the dropdown it get disappeared. I am using angular1 + boostrap 3.3.7 and jquery 1.12.4 library. No other scripting or js is used.

Following is the angular function

```
app.controller("serviceHistoryController",function($scope){    
    let menuitems = [{"sutid":"1","name":"AA"},
                    {"sutid":"2","name":"BB"},
                    {"sutid":"3","name":"CC"},
                    {"sutid":"4","name":"DD"},
                    {"sutid":"4","name":"EE"}]
    $scope.sutlist = menuitems;
    $scope.selectedSUT;

    $scope.sutselected = function(sutname){
        $scope.selectedSUT = sutname;
        alert("dropdown sut selected:"+$scope.selectedSUT.name);
    }   
});
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code => `aria-haspopup="flase"` . it needs to be `false` not `flase`

Comment: expose your sutselected angular function

Comment: @Aravind Please check updated question

Comment: Your problem is that you are using jQuery and Boostrap. Remove both and use Bootstrap UI. You are thinking jQuery instead of thinking Angular.

Comment: @dfsq i am a new to angualr bootstrap, are suggesting me to use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ?

Comment: are you using any jquery or java script?

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap UI is the most popular way to do it.

Comment: Hi , I checked your code works fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with your data type **let** use **var** see the modified controller.

```
app.controller("serviceHistoryController",function($scope){    
    var menuitems = [{"sutid":"1","name":"AA"},
                    {"sutid":"2","name":"BB"},
                    {"sutid":"3","name":"CC"},
                    {"sutid":"4","name":"DD"},
                    {"sutid":"4","name":"EE"}]
    $scope.sutlist = menuitems;
    $scope.selectedSUT;

    $scope.sutselected = function(sutname){
        $scope.selectedSUT = sutname;
        alert("dropdown sut selected:"+$scope.selectedSUT.name);
    }   
});
```

Comment: i have test above, no luck. Also let is a valid data type for es6.

Answer (score 0):

Please See

```js
var app = angular.module('main', []);
app.controller("serviceHistoryController",function($scope){    
    var menuitems = [{"sutid":"1","name":"AA"},
                    {"sutid":"2","name":"BB"},
                    {"sutid":"3","name":"CC"},
                    {"sutid":"4","name":"DD"},
                    {"sutid":"4","name":"EE"}]
    $scope.sutlist = menuitems;
    $scope.selectedSUT;

    $scope.sutselected = function(sutname){
        $scope.selectedSUT = sutname;
        alert("dropdown sut selected:"+$scope.selectedSUT.name);
    }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="main" class="container" ng-controller="serviceHistoryController">
   Normal :  <select>
      <option>select</option>
  <option ng-repeat="sutname in sutlist">  {{sutname.name}}</option>
   </select>
  <br/>  <br/>
    <!-- Search box Start -->
    <div class="dropdown col-xs-8">
         Bootstrap <button class="btn btn-default col-xs-4" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="flase" aria-expanded="true">
           Click Here
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu col-xs-8" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li ng-repeat="sutname in sutlist">
                  <a href="#" ng-click="sutselected(sutname)">
                      {{sutname.name}}
                  </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      
      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In bootstrap dropdown works like button see  http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: :( strange, i don't understand why it is not working with me. this is app module i am usign - let mockapp = angular.module("mockapp",['ngSanitize','ngRoute','ngMessages','ctrlModule']); , also now i am trying with ui-bootstrap